# on local machine my simple js validation works but on jsfiddle it doesn't why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

please see my link on the following link http://jsfiddle.net/3908050/n6g33gqo/3/  i dont know hat is goin on it may be because iam novice to js fiddle

```
 <form onsubmit='return formValidator()'>First Name:
        <input type='text' id='firstname' />
        <br />Address:
        <input type='text' id='addr' />
        <br />Zip Code:
        <input type='text' id='zip' />
        <br />State:
        <select id='state'>
            <option>Please Choose</option>
            <option>AL</option>
            <option>CA</option>
            <option>TX</option>
            <option>WI</option>
        </select>
        <br />Username(6-8 characters):
        <input type='text' id='username' />
        <br />Email:
        <input type='text' id='email' />
        <br />
        <input type='submit' value='Check Form' />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you put the `formValidator()` function inside `$(document).ready` so it's no longer in the global scope, and can't be accessed from inline event handlers like `onsubmit`

You're not really using jQuery, so just remove the DOM ready handler

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/n6g33gqo/5/)